# Force widget painting on contentsRect instead of rect

Tags: windows, qt, user-interface, qpainter

I'm setting `contentsMargins` for widget and want widget to be painted on `contentsRect()` instead of `rect()`. I can do so at `paintEvent` by setting `viewPort` and `clipRegion`, but I don't want to implement `paintEvent` for every type of widget.

Is it possible to force widget painting on `contentsRect` instead of `rect`?

I'm writing analog of mimic creator and want to draw border over each visual component. Just like it's done in Qt creator - when I pick widget at design window, there is a border with resizing points over each widget and I want such border.

Comment: Describe initial problem? Why you need this?

Comment: I'm writing analog of mimic creator and want to draw border over each visual component. Just like it's done in Qt creator - when I pick widget at design window, there is a border with resizing points over each widget and I want such border.

Comment: I want to have some offset from widget rectangle so that border was visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just created sibling `border` class for each visual component, implemented `moved` and `resized` slots for it so that border resized along with widget, and called `stackUnder` for each widget so that border painted over each widget. Thanks for collaboration.